# PHP voting code works on 5.2.5 but not on 5.2.11 anymore

Tags: php

Ok, so a little while back I had some help writing some PHP voting code, it worked just fine after I upgraded my server to use the latest version of PHP. However now I have switched servers, and the PHP isn't as up to date as the other one. Anyways here's my code:

```
<?php
if(!file_exists('vote/1u.txt')){
file_put_contents('vote/1u.txt', '+1');
}
if($_GET['click'] == 'up1'){
file_put_contents('vote/1u.txt', ((int) file_get_contents('vote/1u.txt')) + 1);
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
die;
}
?>
```

Execute and display:

```
<a href="?click=up1"><img src="images/thumbsup.jpg" width="40px"border="0">            </a><br>Votes: <?php echo file_get_contents('vote/up1.txt'); ?>
```

Now when on my other server (PHP version 5.2.5) this code worked great! However on my new server the PHP version is 5.2.11, and because of this the code won't work. My question is, is there any way to make this more compatible with an earlier version of PHP, or to write completely new code that will work just like this one? Or is there a way to tell my servers to use PHP 5.2.5+? I'm using cPanel X admin panel.

*I have set the text file permissions to 777 and still nothing!*

Comment: How is your above code going to work anywhere if you give "click" "yes" instead of "up1"?

Comment: Oh sorry, I took these two codes from two different pages, they have different values on those two different pages so yea. I'll edit that in though.

Comment: Any changes in the php.ini???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are checking for variable "click" but executing the code only if it equals "up1".

But your link tells click to equals "yes" so that part of the code is never true, hence never executed.

Change your executor to this:

```
<a href="?click=up1"><img src="images/thumbsup.jpg" width="40px"border="0">            </a><br>Votes: <?php echo file_get_contents('counteru.txt'); ?>
```

But more logically, your processing code should be rationalized a bit to this:

if the link is clicked :
First, if the data file (lu.txt) does not exist, create it and write '+1' inside of it, else, add 1 to its existing value.

Then, redirects to the initial page.

```
 if($_GET['click'] == 'up1'){
        if(!file_exists('vote/1u.txt')){
            file_put_contents('vote/1u.txt', '+1');
        }else{
            $content = file_get_contents('vote/1u.txt');
            if(!$content){
                  die("Error! file_get_content failed !");
            }
            file_put_contents('vote/1u.txt', ((int)$content) + 1);
        }
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    }

    exit;
```

Comment: I already new that, but These two codes were from two different pages, I just grabbed them for convince. I appreciate it though.

Comment: I did everything you said, added 1 to the value of 1u.txt, updated the code, and still nothing. even with the value set to one it should have displayed something, but nothing. I wonder if file_get_contents is the problem.

Comment: if file_get_contents fails, it return FALSE. I'll update my code to add a check against that.

Answer (score 0):

Not a bad idea to add a trim() around file_get_contents(). Or to check if $_GET['click'] isset() prior to checking if it's equal to 'up1'.

It's conventional to exit() instead of die() after a header redirect--well, from what I've seen at least.

Basically, during development, turn on error reporting and set your error flag to E_ALL to see everything, including warnings and notices--neither of which halt your code, but should still be known and addressed.

You might discover the reason your code produces different outcomes under different minor versions of PHP by turning on full error reporting.

Comment: I did that, however nothing came up. 
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

Comment: Hmm, have your tried running your script both with and without a pre-existing vote/1u.txt file? Does it get created when missing? I assume when you say your code doesn't work that it's not incrmenting an existing file...

Btw, I would refactor your code to this to avoid one extra file_put_contents():

<code>
<?php

$file = 'vote/1u.txt';
$current = file_exists($file) ? (int) trim(file_get_contents($file)) : 1;

if (isset($_GET['click']) and $_GET['click'] == 'up1') {
    file_put_contents($file, $current + 1);
}

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
exit;
</code>

Comment: thanks for the tip, and when I mean it doesn't work I mean the file isn't written too, and it's not displaying text even when I physically write to it. but i'll try your code.

Comment: I tried your code and it still has the same result, I'm about ready to just skip all this and maybe just try something javascript.